# Count common words in two strings

Tags: r, string, text-mining, data-analysis

I have two strings:

```
a <- "Roy lives in Japan and travels to Africa"
b <- "Roy travels Africa with this wife"
```

I am looking to get a count of common words between these strings.

The answer should be 3.

- "Roy"
- "travels"
- "Africa"

being the common words

This is what I tried:

```
stra <- as.data.frame(t(read.table(textConnection(a), sep = " ")))
strb <- as.data.frame(t(read.table(textConnection(b), sep = " ")))
```

Taking unique to avoid repeat counting

```
stra_unique <-as.data.frame(unique(stra$V1))
strb_unique <- as.data.frame(unique(strb$V1))
colnames(stra_unique) <- c("V1")
colnames(strb_unique) <- c("V1")

common_words <-length(merge(stra_unique,strb_unique, by = "V1")$V1)
```

I need to this for a data set with over 2000 and 1200 strings.
Total times I have to evaluate the string is 2000 X 1200. Any quick way, without using loops.

Comment: I am not actually recommending this, but using your "stra" and "strb", you can probably just do `merge(stra, strb)`...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`strsplit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) and [`intersect`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html) from the `base` library:

```
> a <- "Roy lives in Japan and travels to Africa"
> b <- "Roy travels Africa with this wife"
> a_split <- unlist(strsplit(a, sep=" "))
> b_split <- unlist(strsplit(b, sep=" "))
> length(intersect(a_split, b_split))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Argument "sep" needs to be changed to "split" -> a_split <- unlist(strsplit(a, split=" "))

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps, using `intersect` and `str_extract` 
For `multiple strings`, you can either put them as a `list` or as `vector`

```
 vec1 <- c(a,b)
 Reduce(`intersect`,str_extract_all(vec1, "\\w+"))
 #[1] "Roy"     "travels" "Africa"
```

For `faster` options, consider `stringi`

```
 library(stringi)
 Reduce(`intersect`,stri_extract_all_regex(vec1,"\\w+"))
 #[1] "Roy"     "travels" "Africa"
```

For counting:

```
 length(Reduce(`intersect`,stri_extract_all_regex(vec1,"\\w+")))
 #[1] 3
```

Or using `base R`

```
  Reduce(`intersect`,regmatches(vec1,gregexpr("\\w+", vec1)))
  #[1] "Roy"     "travels" "Africa"
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach is generalizable to n vectors:

```
a <- "Roy lives in Japan and travels to Africa"
b <- "Roy travels Africa with this wife"
c <- "Bob also travels Africa for trips but lives in the US unlike Roy."

library(stringi);library(qdapTools)
X <- stri_extract_all_words(list(a, b, c))
X <- mtabulate(X) > 0
Y <- colSums(X) == nrow(X); names(Y)[Y]

[1] "Africa"  "Roy"     "travels"
```