# How to count common words and store the result in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a lot of text sentences that I want to compare but here's Little Red Riding Hood for the example

```
text1 <- "Once upon a time"
text2 <- "there was a dear little girl"
text3 <- "who was loved by everyone who looked at her"
```

I want to create a matrix that counts common words just like this

```
text1_split <- unlist(strsplit(text1, " "))
text2_split <- unlist(strsplit(text2, " "))
text3_split <- unlist(strsplit(text3, " "))

length(intersect(text1_split, text2_split))
length(intersect(text2_split, text3_split))

texts <- c("text1","text2","text3")
data <- data.frame(texts)
data[, texts] <- NA
rownames(data) <- texts
data <- data[,-1]

data[1,1] <- length(intersect(text1_split, text1_split))
data[1,2] <- length(intersect(text1_split, text2_split))
data[1,3] <- length(intersect(text1_split, text3_split))
```

The result of my matrix is this

```
      text1 text2 text3
text1     4     1     0
text2    NA    NA    NA
text3    NA    NA    NA
```

Is there a way to complete the matrix in an efficient way? I have more than 100 sentences to compare. This is a post with something similar but not equal: [Count common words in two strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930550/count-common-words-in-two-strings-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CommonWordsMatrixOld <- function(vList) {
    v <- lapply(vList, tolower)
    do.call(rbind, lapply(v, function(x) {
             xSplit <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
             do.call(c, lapply(v, function(y) length(intersect(xSplit, strsplit(y, " ")[[1]]))))
        }))
}

myText <- list(text1, text2, text3)
```

Calling it we have:

```
CommonWordsMatrixOld(myText)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    1    0
[2,]    1    6    1
[3,]    0    1    8
```

And it is decently fast for data the size the OP is requesting. The data was obtained [here](http://www.rupert.id.au/resources/1000-words.php):

```
testWords <- read.csv("4000-most-common-english-words-csv.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(1111)
myTestText <- lapply(1:100, function(x) {
         paste(testWords[sample(1000:1020, sample(30, 1), replace = TRUE),],collapse = " ")
    })

myTestText[[15]]
[1] "access restaurant video opinion video eventually fresh eventually
 reform credit publish judge Senate publish fresh restaurant publish
 version Senate critical release recall relation version"

system.time(test1 <- CommonWordsMatrixOld(myTestText))
 user  system elapsed 
0.625   0.009   0.646
```

Here is the output:

```
test1[1:10,1:10]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    9    3    5    1    3    4    4    2    2     1
 [2,]    3    5    3    1    1    3    3    0    0     1
 [3,]    5    3   12    0    3    8    4    3    2     1
 [4,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [5,]    3    1    3    0    4    2    1    1    1     0
 [6,]    4    3    8    0    2   13    7    4    1     1
 [7,]    4    3    4    1    1    7   10    4    1     1
 [8,]    2    0    3    0    1    4    4    7    3     0
 [9,]    2    0    2    0    1    1    1    3    4     0
[10,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0     2
```

**Update**

Here is a much faster algorithm that cuts out many unnecessary operations and takes advantage of `lower.tri` while remaining very general.

```
CommonWordsMatrixNew <- function(vList) {
    v <- lapply(vList, function(x) tolower(strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]))
    s <- length(v)
    m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1L:s, function(x) {
        c(rep(0L,(x-1L)), do.call(c, lapply(x:s, function(y) length(intersect(v[[x]], v[[y]])))))
    }))
    m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
    m
}
```

To give you an idea of the performance increase, here are some benchmarks.(It should be noted that the OP's solution isn't splitting the vector, so it is not a true comparison). The New algo is almost twice as fast as the OP's solution.

```
microbenchmark(New=CommonWordsMatrixNew(myTestText), 
               Old=CommonWordsMatrixOld(myTestText),
               Pach=CommonWordsMatrixPach(PreSplit1), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 New  78.64434  79.07127  86.10754  79.72828  81.39679 137.0695    10
 Old 321.49031 323.89835 326.61801 325.75221 328.50877 335.3306    10
Pach 138.34742 143.00504 145.35147 145.17376 148.34699 151.5535    10

identical(CommonWordsMatrixNew(myTestText), CommonWordsMatrixOld(myTestText), CommonWordsMatrixPach(PreSplit1))
[1] TRUE
```

The new algorithm reduces the number of calls to `strsplit` by `n^2 - n` times (e.g. in the example of above, `strplit` gets called `10000` times in the original algo, and only `100` times in the updated version).  Additionally, since the resulting matrix is symmetric, there is no need to compute the interaction between each sentence more than one time, hence the `x = 1:s` and `y = x:s` in the `lapply` functions. The number of computations for these loops reduces from `n^2` to the [nth triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) `= (n*(n+1)/2)` (e.g. in our example above from `10000` to `5050`). After that, we are relying on the power of indexing in `R`, which is generally much faster than manually manufacturing.

Comment: thanks a lot, below I have posted something based on your reply that seems to be faster

Comment: @pachamaltese, The first algorithm was making unnecessary computations. I have modified my original algorithm to cut out many operations. Also, the algos above remain general (i.e. they don't rely on pre-split vectors). Btw, nice question.

Comment: good point ! I have pre-splitted by using strsplit before the function itself

Answer (score 0):

I found that splitting beforehand increases speed so that

```
CommonWordsMatrix <- function(vList) {
  v <- lapply(vList, tolower)
  do.call(rbind, lapply(v, function(x) {
    do.call(c, lapply(v, function(y) length(intersect(x, y))))
  }))
}
```

is a nice choice to go (x and y are pre-splitted vectors of words)