# R: How to pick common words or same numbers in 2 columns from a very large table with a fast way?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have a very large table (1,000,000 X 20) to process and need to do it in a fast way.

For example, There are 2 columns X2 and X3 in my table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2UXe.jpg)

```
    X1  X2                                          X3
c1  1   100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003003    100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003004
c2  2   100020003001, 100020004002, 100020004003    100020003001, 100020004007, 100020004009
c3  3   100050006003, 100050006001, 100050006001    100050006011, 100050006013, 100050006021
```

Now I would like to create 2 new columns which contain

1) the common words or the same numbers

For example: `[1] "100020003001" "100020003002"`

2) the count of the common words or the same numbers

For example: `[1] 2`

I have tried the method from the below thread, however, the processing time is slow since I did it with for loop:

[Count common words in two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930550/count-common-words-in-two-strings)

```
 library(stringi)
 Reduce(`intersect`,stri_extract_all_regex(vec1,"\\w+"))
```

Thanks for the help!
I am really struggling here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the 'X2', 'X3' columns by the `,`, get the `intersect` of corresponding `list` elements with `map2` and use `lengths` to 'count' the number of elements in the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(common_words = map2(strsplit(X2, ", "),
                              strsplit(X3, ", "),  
                                   intersect), 
          count = lengths(common_words))
# X1                                       X2                                       X3
#1  1 100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003003 100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003004
#2  2 100020003001, 100020004002, 100020004003 100020003001, 100020004007, 100020004009
#3  3 100050006003, 100050006001, 100050006001 100050006011, 100050006013, 100050006021
#                common_words count
#1 100020003001, 100020003002     2
#2               100020003001     1
#3                                0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$common_words <- Map(intersect, strsplit(df1$X2, ", "), strsplit(df1$X3, ", "))
df1$count <- lengths(df1$common_words)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = c("100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003003", 
"100020003001, 100020004002, 100020004003", "100050006003, 
 100050006001, 100050006001"
 ), X3 = c("100020003001, 100020003002, 100020003004", "100020003001, 
 100020004007, 100020004009", 
 "100050006011, 100050006013, 100050006021")), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c("c1", "c2", "c3"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, you helped me twice :) The process takes only several seconds!