# Merging two data frame based on maximum numbers of words in commonin R

Tags: r, stringr, sqldf, stringdist, fuzzyjoin

I have two data.frame one containing partial name and the other one containing full name as follow

```
partial <- data.frame( "partial.name" = c("Apple", "Apple", "WWF",
"wizz air", "WeMove.eu", "ILU")
full <- data.frame("full.name" = c("Apple Inc", "wizzair", "We Move Europe",
"World Wide Fundation (WWF)", "(ILU)", "Ilusion")
```

In the ideal world, I would love to have a table like this (my real partial df has 12 794 rows)

```
print(partial)
partial full
Apple   Apple Inc
Apple   Apple Inc
WWF World Wide Fundation (WWF)
wizz air wizzair
WeMove.eu We Move Europe
... 12 794 total rows
```

For every row without an answer I would like to be `NA`

I tried many things, `fuzzyjoin` with `regex`, `regex_left_join` even with the package `sqldf`. I have some results but I know it would be better if  `regex_left_join`  understand that I am looking for words I know in  `stringr` ,  `boundary( type = c("word"))`  exist but I do not know of to implement it.

For now, I just prepared the partial df, to get rid of the non-alphanumerical information and to make it lowercase.

```
partial$regex <- str_squish((str_replace_all(partial$partial.name, regex("\\W+"), " ")))
partial$regex <- tolower(partial$regex)
```

How can I match  `partial$partial.name`  with  `full$full.name`  based on the maximum number of words in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial string matching is time consuming to get right. I believe the Jaro-Winkler distance is a good candidate but you would need to spend time tweaking parameters. Here's an example to get you going.

```
library(stringdist)

partial <- data.frame( "partial.name" = c("Apple", "Apple", "WWF", "wizz air", "WeMove.eu", "ILU", 'None'), stringsAsFactors = F)
full <- data.frame("full.name" = c("Apple Inc", "wizzair", "We Move Europe", "World Wide Foundation (WWF)", "(ILU)", "Ilusion"), stringsAsFactors = F)

mydist <- function(partial, list_of_fulls, method='jw', p = 0, threshold = 0.4) {
    find_dist <- function(first, second, method = method, p = p) {
        stringdist(a = first, b = second, method = method, p = p)
    }
    distances <- unlist(lapply(list_of_fulls, function(full) find_dist(first = full, second = partial, method = method, p = p)))
    # If the distance is too great assume NA 
    if (min(distances) > threshold) {
        NA
    } else {
        closest_index <- which.min(distances)
        list_of_fulls[closest_index]
    }
}

partial$match <- unlist(lapply(partial$partial.name, function(partial) mydist(partial = partial, list_of_fulls = full$full.name, method = 'jw')))

partial
#  partial.name                       match
#1        Apple                   Apple Inc
#2        Apple                   Apple Inc
#3          WWF World Wide Foundation (WWF)
#4     wizz air                     wizzair
#5    WeMove.eu              We Move Europe
#6          ILU                       (ILU)
#7         None                        <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sadly it does not give great results, would it be possible to create a function based on finding the highest number of matching words based on something like this? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930550/count-common-words-in-two-strings I am trying but this is definitely too hard for me to make it right apparently !

Comment: I opened a new question trying to make it clearer. Thank you again for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452050/finding-the-highest-number-of-matching-word-between-two-string-lists-in-r